# How to use HandlebarsJS helper

Tags: handlebars.js

I have an array like below.

[image]

I have template like below.

```
    <tbody>
        {{#each this.catalog_number}}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ this }}
                </td>               
                {{#each (show_data this.data) }}
                    <td>
                        {{ this }}
                    </td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

My helper is like below

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("show_data", (data_array) => {
    return data_array.CATALOG_NUMBER;
});
```

I am getting error like below.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data_array is undefined
```

Comment: I think the second parameter of the function is an array with the positional params.

Comment: It looks like you need to change the evaluation context with a path like `../data` instead of `this.data` because `data` is _not_ a part of the current context. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context